# Arduino: convert analogRead from photodiode in a distance in cm or mm?

Tags: arduino, sensor, photodiode, distance

I am doing a very simple project on Arduino consisting of an IR LED and a photodiode that measure the distance from an obstacle. I am using an Arduino Nano BLE that has a 12-bit ADC converter.

I am using the analogRead function to read from the photodiode which gives me a reading of like 300 when very close to the obstacle and almost zero (not exactly because of the dark current) far away. How do I convert this measurement in a distance in cm or mm?

Comment: What you are reading is a measurement of light intensity hitting the photodiode from the LED and other unspecified light sources. Can you think of several ways that this might (not very reliably) be converted to distance?

Comment: There are much simpler mechanical variable resistances why use a LED and a photodiode?

Comment: What range do you need and accuracy? What is the reflector? And IR reflection coefficient and geometry directly back to detector? Possible solutions exist but not without specs of aperture beamwidth , range and Kr

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an integrated infrared distance sensor or a IR LED on one side and the photodiode on the other side, trying to measure the distance between both.

In both cases, you will not get a linear relationship.

So, only if the manufacturer gives it to you, there is only one way : do a calibration.

So I suggest that you measure the sensor value at different distances spread across the range of distances you are interested in. Then you plot those point in Excel or Calc. You then decide which regression curve fits rather well (you might try several). Taking the regression parameters from Excel/Calc, you can then compute the distance on the arduino.

Comment: Hi Sandro! I am using an IR LED and a Photodiode, both facing an object. I will try your way

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Answer (score 0):

When you consider emitter distance, d to a  reflector area,  , with IR reflection coefficient \$k_R<1\$, the reflect sees only a fraction of the cone of light that varies with distance, \$d^2\$ and percentage of energy from cone angle.  Not all the energy sensing reflected back to the detector due to angular geometry and reflectivity Kr and orientation and aperture beamwidth of the  detector as point sources from one side. the reflected IR power drops with \$Pin=k_R*(2d)^2\$  thus increases attenuation, and the received power drops by the same 2nd order loss, now attenuation is at best, \$k_R(2d)^4\$, so it is only useful for a very small range with a limited SNR and ADC resolution.  Thus for a 5mm aperture and detector, a 5 cm gap is attenuated from reflective points on the target if kR=1 by \$20 log(10^4)=80dB\$

One solution hypothetically exists for 5mm emitters and detectors with <10 deg beam width recessed into holes to limit as well stray noise light. For short ranges < aperture hole width it is inverse 2d linear, then becomes inverse square of total path, 2d squared assuming perfect reflection. Better solutions use AGC with log amplifiers to measure >80 dB such as modulated carriers @16kHz using remote control AM modulation or IRDA2 detectors with vary narrow beam emitters.

Comment: I am using this photodiode https://www.vishay.com/docs/83471/tefd4300.pdf and this IR LED https://www.vishay.com/docs/81040/tssf4500.pdf. I am supposed to use this for a really close range (inferior to 5 cm or so) as the rest of measurement is done with an ultrasound sensor.

Comment: If you only need 5cm range,  are  +/-20 deg lens optimal?, also what is object size and kR